# How can I set built in version number in a binary?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, g++

While compiling a binary with gcc, I want to set a built in version number, which I may retrieve whenever required as `foo -v`. The goal is to identify latest binary among many binaries with same name. The version should be automatically updated for each compilation.

Currently, I am using macros like `__DATE__ __TIME__` to get compilation date time information about binary. I also tried to verify md5, to know which binary version is, but package manager like `rpmbuil` may change md5 while build, thus, it's not that much helpful.

If it is not possible to automatically update version number for each compilation, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a file to store the version number, or represent the version number. Let your build update the file. The compiler invocation can just define a macro with the version number.